# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function error

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I am using typeahead in my application and I have included it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css"/> 
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

But still I am getting typeahead is not a function error. I have even included jquery 1.10.2 version file. Below is my code

```
<script>
var docarray=[];
var condarray=[];
var specarray=[];
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var doctorjsonurl = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/doctorfeed/doctortypeahead.jsp";//just for security
    $.ajax({
        type :"GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url : "/childrensplugin/proxy.jsp?reqUrl="+encodeURIComponent(doctorjsonurl),
        success : function(data){
         for(i=0;i<data.doctornames.length;i++){
              docarray.push(data.doctornames[i]);
            }
            var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
                return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                    var matches, substringRegex;                       
                    matches = [];                        
                    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');                        
                    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                            matches.push(str);
                        }
                    });
                    cb(matches);
                };
            };
            $('#the-doc .typeaheaddoc').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 3
            },
            {
                name: '',
                source: substringMatcher(docarray)
            });
            },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         //   alert(xhr.status);
         //   alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
var condjsonurl = "http://xxxxxxxx/doctorfeed/condtreatsforcondtreatsearchtypeahead.jsp";
    $.ajax({
        type :"GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url : "/childrensplugin/proxy.jsp?reqUrl="+encodeURIComponent(condjsonurl),
        success : function(data){

         for(i=0;i<data.allconditions.length;i++){
              specarray.push(data.allconditions[i]);
            }

            for(i=0;i<data.alltreatments.length;i++){
              specarray.push(data.alltreatments[i]);
            }   

            var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
                return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                    var matches, substringRegex;                       
                    matches = [];                       
                    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');                        
                    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                            matches.push(str);
                        }
                    });
                    cb(matches);
                };
            };
            $('#the-cond .typeaheadcond').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            },
            {
                name: '',
                source: substringMatcher(specarray)
            });
            },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         //   alert(xhr.status);
         //   alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here..

Comment: Where have you included this script ? I hope after loading all the other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place  tag in the head
2. Place your code in  preferably preceeding

Comment: Your unescaped html tags make this answer rather cryptic.